# Execute child process in Node which takes control of the console

Tags: node.js, git, child-process

I'd like to run a command from Node like `git commit`. I can do that by doing:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
exec("git commit", function(error, stderr, stdout) {
  // Do stuff
});
```

However, it always hangs. I assume this is because `git commit` wants to take control of the console to open vim/emacs or whatever, but Node isn't allowing it. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using spawn instead of exec so you can inherit the stdio.

```
'use strict';

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var commit = spawn('git', ['commit'], {stdio : 'inherit'});
```